# Python 2.7 vs Python 3.3 for Django development

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x

We are just starting some cloud-based apps based on Python + Django and we have a small dilemma. At first we decided to go with Python 3.3, but than we saw that a lot of libraries/modules have not been ported yet, thus we might have to do extra work to make sure that everything works with Python 3.3.

Given the fact that the projects that we are starting will have a time frame of a few years what advice would you give us? To go with Python 2.7 or Python 3.3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dilemma is of course that Python3 is the superior language, and is the future of the language, but 3rd party suppliers are being slow about porting.  So I'll second Ignacio's advice below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go with Python 2.7 for now. Make sure that your code translates cleanly when using [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html). When the modules are available for Python 3.x, translate your code and run with it.